# using a variable to populate the "mailto:" value using "form action"

Tags: html, forms, mailto

Newbie question no.2, sorry in advance!

I have somehow managed to create a form with various selection boxes, one of which is the email that the form should send the email to (using mailto:). I've managed to get the value of the email field stored as a variable ("emailtouse"), and now I am trying to use the variable in the "mailto:" code but it's not having it, I either get blank or the variable name itself when I attempt the process.

Thanks
Ian

```
***variable setting within script in header***
 var emailtouse = "mailto:"+emailgoto[value]

***form action***

<form action='+emailtouse+'? 
cc=u16@myleague.co.uk&subject=Match%20Postponement/%20Cancellation%20Request" method="post" 
enctype="text/plain">
```

Comment: [`mailto:` urls for form actions are hopelessly unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). Don't use them at all.

Comment: I think you may be assuming that the value of the ```emailtouse``` variable is reactive - i.e., that it will update once user enters something into the eimail field.
However, this is not the case - to get a reactive variable, you can use one of the js frameworks, like alpine.js or vue

Comment: @CJK - thanks, I have the variable to set after the change event of the first drop down based on a coded value i.e. users select "Under 7" it will set another drop down to "under7@football.co.uk" which then is used as the variable. I have added an alert to show it's definitely (in my eyes anyway!) picking up the value. So if I wanted to (whether I should or not is moot as this is just proof of concept stuff) how would I do it please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if your variable is updated, the "action" is not updated after the variable changes, so it contains the original value, calculated upon rendering the page.
Please see the following CodePen example on how to update the form action before submit:

```
    <form 
          id="form1"
          onsubmit="return updateAction(this)"
          action="javascript:;" 
          method="post">
      <button type="submit">Do it!</button>
    </form>
```

... and the JS to update the form action, and to test that it really worked:

```js
    let emailtouse = "testemail@somewhere.com";
    
    function updateAction(element) {
      element.action =
        emailtouse +
        "&cc=u16@myleague.co.uk&subject=Match%20Postponement/%20Cancellation%20Request";
      checkIfItReallyWorks();
      return false; // change to true to submit!!!
    }
    
    function checkIfItReallyWorks() {
      let form = document.getElementById("form1");
      alert(form.action);
    }
```

The above code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/cjkpl/pen/vYxPJQd